# SSAS (Analysis Services) 2014 - Cumulative Update 1 for SP1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssas

I just recently applied CU1 for SQL Server 2014 SP1 (http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3067839) to my development workstation and one PROD server. Analysis Services continues to report itself as build 12.0.4100.1 (which is SP1) and not build 12.0.4416.0. Given that there are quite a few SSAS fixes in this update, this doesn't seem to be right.

When I look at the file information for CU 8 (http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3067836), I see a whole host of SSAS file updates that I do not see in CU 1 for Service Pack 1.  From my outside-of-Microsoft perspective, it seems that the SSAS updates were not included in this update as advertised.

Can anyone corroborate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late yesterday (7/8/2015), the Microsoft SQL Server Engineering Team confirmed that the Analysis Services hotfixes were indeed missing from the release of this CU. They intend to fix this in CU2 for SQL Server 2014 SP1.  More information in the update message on the bottom of their blog post: [link to SQL Release Services blog entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlreleaseservices/cumulative-update-1-for-sql-server-2014-sp1)